# Create directory in Android Ddevice

Tags: android, file, permissions

I'm having problems creating directories with Android Studio in an old  phone (v 4.4.4), I've tried in more modern phones and it works, here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DIRECTORY";
    private Button click;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        click.setOnClickListener(v -> getAlbumStorageDir(this, "samuel_es_dios"));
    }

    public void getAlbumStorageDir(Context context, String albumName) {

        pedirPermisos();
        // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/"+ albumName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
        }else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory created");
        }
    }

    private void pedirPermisos() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},50);
        }
    }
}
```

**And here's the Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="iam47662285.escoladeltreball.org.pruebasfile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When it tries to create the directory it doesn't do it, I don't think that's a problem of permissions, I directly ask for them. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Is there anything in your logcat indicating an error, if so post it here

Comment: There's no error in logcat, that's the problem

Comment: `problems creating directories with Android Studio` ??? Android Studio cannot create directories on an Android device. And i think your Android app is trying that.

Comment: Maybe you need the READ permission too.

Comment: `if (!file.mkdirs())`. Wrong! You should not blindly and always call mkdirs(). Only if the directory does not exist yet. Check with file.exists().

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which type of view it is So as you have done

`click = findviewbyid(R.id.button)`

Change it to

`click=(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button)`

Comment: In the new versions of Android Studio you don't need to do that